# Bitcoin Cash totally different from BTC?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I hear everyone talking as if when you have Bitcoin it is a matter of *transferring in order to access* your Bitcoin Cash instead of trading like other coins.

I was under the impression that it was an entirely separate coin and one would obtain it in the same way that one would obtain Ethereum if he had bitcoin by trading it correct?

Or if you have bitcoin do you at the same time have that much in BCC and it just needs to be moved somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTC and BCC share a transaction history. Thus, to each blockchain, anyone holding a coin before the split has a coin in their address on each blockchain.

Comment: So if BCC were to shoot off and 1 BCC became worth $3000 USD for example would everyone who owned BTC before the split and kept it automatically benefit from this rise in price?

Comment: not exactly.
you have to sell it to benefit from a price rise, the realization of value is not automatic.
Both chains would need active miners to give the coin value and enable its transfer to an exchange